# Covariance stationarity of AR in time series

Tags: covariance, time-series, stationary-processes

I have an extremely basic question of time series on covariance stationarity. Consider
$$
Y_t=\gamma Y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t
$$
where $\epsilon_t$ is such that $E(\epsilon_t)=0$ $\forall t$, $Var(\epsilon_t)=E(\epsilon_t^2)=\sigma^2>0$ $\forall t$, $cov(\epsilon_t, \epsilon_s)=E(\epsilon_t \epsilon_s)=0$ $\forall s\neq t$ (i.e. $\epsilon_t$ is a white noise).

Suppose that $\gamma=1$ and $(Y_0, Y_1)=(0,0)$. I want to show that $\{Y_t\}_t$ is not covariance stationary.

I know that $\{Y_t\}_t$ is covariance stationary if $E(Y_t)$ does not depend on $t$ and $cov (Y_t, Y_{t-k})$ is independent of $t$ for $k=0,1,...$, $\forall t$.

Let's consider $Var(Y_t)$ for $t=3,4$
$$
Var(Y_3)= Var(\gamma \underbrace{Y_1}_0+\epsilon_3)=Var(\epsilon_3)=\sigma^2
$$
and
$$
Var(Y_4)= Var(\gamma Y_2+\epsilon_4)=Var(\gamma(\gamma\underbrace{Y_0}_0+\epsilon_2) +\epsilon_4)=Var(\gamma \epsilon_2+\epsilon_4)= \sigma^2(\gamma^2+1)\underbrace{=}_{\gamma=1} 2\sigma^2\neq Var(Y_3)
$$
Hence $\{Y_t\}_t$ is not covariance stationary.

---

**Question**: a sufficient condition for covariance stationarity is to have the roots of the polynomial equation
$$
1-\gamma L^2=0
$$
greater than $1$ in absolute value, i.e. 
$$
\begin{cases}
|\frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}|>1\\
|-  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}|>1\\
\end{cases}
$$
$\leftrightarrow$ $|\gamma|<1$

Now, if I consider $\gamma=0.5$, we can see that the sufficient condition of covariance stationarity is satisfied but still $Var(Y_4)\neq Var(Y_3)$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you initiate your process at time zero, while an $\operatorname{AR}$ process does not have an initialization time. Instead, what we would do is call the process with a start an *approximation*. Results exist about choosing optimal choice of the initial time point value (which in your case indeed is 0). The process is simply not covariance stationary close to an initialization point. This is treated in many texts about the subject under the headline **stability**.

---

Instead use the results about the polynomial as you do in your second method. From there it follows that for your case of $\gamma = 1$, the process is indeed not stationary (it is a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk)) and your second example with $\gamma = 0.5$, it *is* stationary.

Comment: thanks. One question: the conditions about the polynomial are necessary and sufficient?

Comment: It is a necessary and sufficient condition for (weak/strong) stationarity of an $\operatorname{AR}(p)$ model with representation $\phi(B) Y_t = \varepsilon_t$ that the polynomial $\phi(z) = 1-\gamma_1z - \ldots - \gamma_p z^p$ does not have roots on $\{z\in \mathbb C: \lvert z \rvert = 1\}$ when $\{\varepsilon_t\}$ is a (weak/strong) white noise. Here $B$ is the backwards shift operator.